# How can I gain more freedom of camera rotation in a UDK game?

Tags: camera, unreal-development-kit, unrealscript

I have a game concept being designed in UDK, using a first-person camera. By default, you can only look (i.e. rotate the camera) so far up and so far down, but the effect I want to achieve is for the player to be able to look down at themselves so they can see the feet of the player character's model, as you can in the game Outlast for anyone who's familiar with that.

I'm a programmer more than a designer, so I'm hoping there's a scripting solution to this.  I presume I need to extend one or more of the Camera, PlayerController and Pawn classes, but I've had a browse through them and can't quite find what I'm looking for. Presumably there are min and max values for rotation angles hiding somewhere?

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Just begin with unhiding the player skeletal mesh to see the feet and body of the player.Then, tweak with the camera properties to adjust the camera position and limiting the rotation angles. It is definetely possible.

Answer (score -1):

The default UDK game, as does a lot of other FPS games, cheats when it comes to first-person because it only renders the arms and the gun. In fact, there is no 1P player model at all! The gun skeleton controls the arm animations and "owns" the arms mesh.

You can get around this by moving your game into a third-person perspective (using a 3P player mesh), but then mounting the camera to the player's head socket. This is what is known as "[True First Person](http://krisredbeard.wordpress.com/projects/tfp-demo/)". Follow the link for a great sample implementation.

Comment: In fact, this is quite wrong in my own experiments. The condition you are talking about is, the player mesh is explicitly hidden in first person mode.If you override it with your own class and unhide the player mesh, you can see the player character, flesh and bone. You have to arrange the camera a little bit but it is definetely possible in first person mode.